# How can I suppress dialyzer warning on comparison between module variable and local static variable?

Tags: elixir, dialyzer

Dialyzer blames the code trying to match against module variable:

```
defmodule Main do
  # -> :demo
  @env Application.get_env(:myproject, :env)

  def run do
    case @env do
      :production -> 1
      _ -> 2
    end
  end
end
```

```
lib/myproject/main.ex:6:pattern_match
The pattern can never match the type.

Pattern:
:production

Type:
:demo
```

How can I avoid the warning, or should I write as below every time?

```
  def run do
    env = Application.get_env(:myproject, :env)

    case env do
      ...
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> should I write as below every time?

It depends on what are you trying to achieve. `dialyzer` is smart. Module attributes are *compile time beasts*, they are computed and replaced everywhere during the compilation time. What gets into BEAM in the snippet above would be:

```rb
defmodule Main do
  def run do
    case :demo do
      :production -> 1
      _ -> 2
    end
  end
end
```

That said, `dialyzer` warns you about an unreachable statement because it analyses *the resulting code*, with all the macros expanded *and* module attributes inplaced.

If you want the different compiled code depending on the environment, you have several approaches.

1. Explicitly suppress dialyzer warning as [described here](https://github.com/jeremyjh/dialyxir#ignore-warnings).
2. Trick the dialyzer (examples might be found in *Elixir* core, I would not paste those here because I do not find this solution robust enough.)
3. Call `Application.get_env(:myproject, :env)` directly in the `case` clause (or assign to the local variable as you suggested.)

The latter approach is IMSO *preferrable*.